# If two metric spaces are Cauchy-equivalent, then are they topologically equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

If two metrics $d_i$ on the same set $X$ have the same Cauchy sequences (i.e. if a sequence is Cauchy for the first metric, it is also Cauchy for the other one and vice versa), does this imply that the two metric spaces are equivalent (i.e. generate the same topology)?

Please help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that if $d_1$ and $d_2$ have the same Cauchy sequences, then they also have the same limits. If $\{a_n\}\rightarrow b$ in $d_1$, then consider the sequence $a_0, b, a_1, b, a_2, b, . . . $. Clearly this is Cauchy in $d_1$, so Cauchy in $d_2$, but that means it (and so the original sequence) must approach $b$ in $d_2$.

Now suppose $C$ is not closed with respect to $d_2$ but closed with respect to $d_1$. Taking $a$ in the $d_2$-closure of $C$ but not in $C$; then we can get a Cauchy sequence of elements of $C$ which $d_2$-approaches $a$ . . .

By symmetry, we get that every $d_2$-closed set is $d_1$-closed. Since $d_1$ and $d_2$ have the same notion of "closedness," they induce the same topologies on $X$.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question. Could you give me an explanation?

Comment: @JohnMars It shows that $d_1$ and $d_2$ have the same notion of "closedness" (I've shown that "closed in $d_1$" implies "closed in $d_2$," and we get the converse closure via symmetry). That means that they induce the same topologies.

Comment: Alternatively you can think in terms of [closure operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/). The argument above (+ symmetry) shows that the topologies induced by $d_1$ and $d_2$ have the same "sequential closure" operators; since sequential closure = closure for metrizable spaces, this means that they have the same closure operators, which is to say they are actually the same topology.

Comment: @JohnMars I've edited to make this explicit.